# How do I implement a simple spin lock using FetchAndAdd

Tags: c, locks, spinlock

Tried something like this:

```
typedef struct __lock_t { 
  int flag;
} lock_t;

void init(lock_t *lock) {
  lock->flag = 0;
}

void lock(lock_t *lock) 
{
   while (FetchAndAdd(&lock->flag) != 0)
   ; // spin-wait (do nothing)
}

void unlock(lock_t *lock)
{
  lock->flag = 0;
}
```

Is this the proper way of implementing simple spin lock using fetch and add lock mechanism? If not, then what changes should be made?

Comment: Which architecture? Which language?

Comment: operating system. C language

Comment: Which CPU? Intel?

Comment: For "C abstract machine"; I think `lock->flag` needs to be volatile and/or atomic (otherwise there's no guarantee that other CPUs/threads will be able to see that `lock->flag = 0;` occurred); but otherwise it looks correct. I don't know if "merely correct" is considered "the proper way" (for my personal opinion, "the proper way" excludes artificial restrictions like "must use FetchAndAdd").